# How can I get the worker address for Celery's app.control.broadcast

Tags: python, django, celery

I wish to broadcast a panel command to a specific worker using app.control.broadcast, using the destination parameter.

What exactly does the destination list expect as an address to a worker?  And how can I get that address *from the worker* (which I know is an unusual request but is easiest for my workflow here.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not ideal, but I managed it with:

Get the thread name on the worker:

```
from celery.signals import celeryd_after_setup

@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def capture_worker_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    worker_thread_name = '{0}'.format(sender)
    print("Celery worker name: " + worker_thread_name)
    app.conf["worker_thread_name"] = worker_thread_name
```

It's not ideal because that will only work for one worker on a machine.

You can get a list of the worker addresses on the "client" with:

```
app.control.inspect().stats().keys()
```

Which is also helpful.  I haven't found out yet wether a Celery Result object contains the worker address, which would also do the trick for me.